# Select List in slds limit

Tags: slds

Is there any limit on how many options are displayed in slds SelectList?
I see that a few values are not showing up in the select list. I have not specified any filter or anything as such

```
<apex:inputField value{!controller.pickListOptions} styleClass="slds-select slds-input"/>
```

Comment: Post your code, is the view restricting the view of some of the values?

Comment: @EricSSH, <apex:inputField value{!controller.pickListOptions} styleClass="slds-select slds-input"/> Just iputfield with styleclass slds-select and slds-input

Comment: Considering you are using *inputField* here, the same [limitation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=picklist_limitations.htm&type=5) should apply as what it is for a standard picklist field.

Answer (score 0):

---

**UPDATE:**

As for your visibility issue using SLDS, there's no such restriction either. I verified with the same style class on a VF page and was able to display all of the [Country Codes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklists_configure.htm&type=5) available out of the box.

---

This answer is specific to the limits question. If you are not able to view values, then if you can update with some specifics in your original post as what is being shown vs. what not shown, will help from there. There may be possibility that you have record types for the object and that those values are not available for that record type.

As for your original question, if you are using `<apex:inputField>`, then your [limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=picklist_limitations.htm&type=5) are same as what is applicable for the picklist field. That would necessarily mean that it can only contain values as below, let's say if you use a custom object.

> Custom single-select picklists can have:
>
> - Up to 1,000 values
> - Up to 255 characters per value

Additionally, I would think that in case of `<apex:selectList>`, it depends on the data type say that of *List* how many values it can contain.

But you definitely don't want to have a long picklist even if out of the box allows 1000 values to be displayed to a User, that won't be a good user experience at all.

Comment: I have say 50 values in picklist but in the UI it's showing 47. The page with no SLDS styling is showing all 50 values. The only difference is styling.

Comment: Do you have record types and that there is a possibility that some of the values are not available for that picklist field?

Comment: No recordtypes involved. It's a custom field of type picklist on a custom object.

Comment: You may like to post a different question, with details on your implementation. As for the limits, the limit remains same as for the field in consideration from the platform perspective. Also you may like to edit the question here as it does not really have anything to do with SLDS. Btw, does removing the style class display all the values?